# mootools self reference

Tags: mootools, this, self

how can i handle a self-reference in mootools?
After i made the next container visible, i would remove the clicked "remove" Button.
With Jquery i can do it throug the "this" operator.

```
 window.addEvent('domready', function(){

        $$('div.showButton').addEvent('click', function(){

        // show next Container 
        $$('div.container').getNext().show('inline');   

        // remove this "showButton"
        $(this).remove() // not working

        });
        });





   <!-- container 1 -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="showButton">Show next container</div>
        <div class="hideButton">hide this container</div>

    </div>

    <!-- container 2 -->
    <div class="container" style="display:none">

        <div class="showButton">Show next container</div>
        <div class="hideButton">hide this container</div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember mootools is not jquery and they different in the implementation of stuff.

First the $$ function return array of elements and not element so you can't call show on an array - you have to take the element you want (usually it's the first).

Second - you can call the current element using $(this) but it's a bit unnecessary because you are already inside the element event so you just can use "this":

http://jsfiddle.net/kk4gz/2/

```
    $$('div.showButton').addEvent('click', function(){

       // show next Container 
       $$('div.container')[0].getNext().show('inline');   

       // remove this "showButton"
       this.remove();

    });
```

Comment: Additionally if you ever lose `this`, for most events there's target element available: `$element.addEvent('click', function(e){ e.target.remove(); )}`